# What are the ways to update an UI in android other than SharedPreferences and Services?

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences, storage

I would like to update the UI using the data which I don't want to be stored in SharedPreferences(as it is local) and also don't want it to be handled by the Services(as it may consumes lot of resources, drains battery, etc.,).

As intent may not provide so much functionalities as the SharedPreferences framework provide, I would like to if there is any alternatives for updating the UI than SharedPreferences, Services and Intents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sqlite database.

check these links https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/